# Why developers sometime are not using Object Associations: Aggregation and Containment

Tags: c#, oop

I had browsed a couple of asp.net application form asp.net

I see some example not use OOP Aggregation or Containment  like  http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/job for exaple the 
developer use countryID instead of country object in  my job posting class and company class.

I want to know if this way is recommended or not [image]

```
 public class JobPosting
    {

        #region Member Variables

        private int intJobPostingID;
        private int intCompanyID;
        private string strContactPerson;
        private string strTitle;
        private string strDepartment;
        private string strJobCode;
        private string strCity;
        private int intStateID;
        private int intCountryID;
        private int intEducationLevelID;
        private int intJobTypeID;
        private decimal dblMinSalary;
        private decimal dblMaxSalary;
        private string strDescription;
        private DateTime dtPostingDate=DateTime.Now;
        private string strPostedBy=HttpContext.Current.Profile.UserName;

   }

   public class Country
   {


        private string strCountryName;
        private int intCountryID;
        public Country()
        {
        }
   }


    public class Company
    {
        private int intCompanyID;
        private string strUserName;

        private string strCompanyName;
        private string strBriefProfile;

        private string strAddress1;
        private string strAddress2;
        private string strCity;
        private int intStateID;
        private int intCountryID;
        private string strZIP;

        private string strPhone;
        private string strFax;
        private string strEmail;
        private string strWebSiteUrl;
}
```

Comment: Some times what you find in the internet need not be perfect and fine tuned. After all these are humans who are writing it. This might be just the case of Developer not being aware of the concept or omitting it by purpose

Comment: Its recommended or not based only on the situation.

Comment: Just I was looking for some example becosue I'm junior level  developer. and I am working alone and looking for advice

Comment: What you are expecting is correct only, its just that in this specific case the developer has not implemented it.

Comment: Hard to answer... People write all kinds of code for all kinds of reasons. It is impossible to explain (and often even guess) why particular code style was chosen (or happened). I.e. code that uses `HttpContext.Current` may contain all sorts of other bits that some people will consider bad... or beautiful... depending on ones mood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you've shown, including the Country rather than countryId is recommended.ORM frameworks are specifically meant for that. The domain model should follow oop principles such as composition and inheritance, and ORM will bridge the gap between DB and domain model.

Comment: thank but I am not criticize the developer but because i need good resource or tut or advice in how map my object to my database and sorry I look at EF but my manager don't want to adapted because of our old code

Comment: You are quite right. I think you should try and convince your manager about how evolved frameworks such as EF are, and tell him that the code also should ideally keep pace with technology. Moreover there is plenty of support available out there for these technologies. So good luck!